# Basic Auth, falling back to Forms auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, basic-authentication

This is a question regarding ASP.net MVC 4. You can assume SSL throughout.

- I have a Web API which will be available to clients over SSL using HTTP Basic Auth.
- I also have a CMS, on the same domain, which uses the Web API via jQuery.
- The user logs into the CMS over Forms auth.

For this reason I would like that it be possible to login to the Web API using *either* HTTP Basic Auth or Forms auth.

I plan to implement this using a custom AuthorizeAttribute, which will first check the basic auth header against the database if present. If the basic auth header is not present, then it will delegate authorization to the base AuthorizeAttribute to handle Forms auth.

First of all, is this a good idea? Can anyone see any problems in allowing either type of auth? Can anyone see any implementation problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, is this a good idea?

Yes, it seems like a good idea and I do not see anything wrong with implementing 2 types of authentication mechanisms:

- Forms authentication for users that are already authenticated on the same domain
- Basic authentication for users that are not yet authenticated but posses a username and password and want to directly invoke some method of your Web API